# Regex To Delete <ahref> tags but leave url

Tags: regex

im rubbish with regex if someone could help id be very appreciative.

its going to be a bit of a tough one i imagine - so my hats off too anyone that can solve it!

so say we have file that contains 2 html tags in the following formats:

```
abc1234
<a href="http://google.com">Some Text</a> <P>
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="nofollow">Some Text</a>
abc1234
```

im trying to remove everything in those tags except the url (and leaving other text) so the output of the regex in this document would be

```
abc1234
http://google.com <P>
http://www.google.com
abc1234
```

Can any guru figure this one out? Id prefer one regex expression to handle both cases but two seperate ones would be fine too.

Thanks in advance/

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? What language are you trying this in?

Comment: Im a complete noob when it comes to regex, i have no hope in solving this. i did attempt it and only managed to create something that deletes every html tag in the document. which was not very helpful! Its a third party tool that modifys text and accepts regex and i have no idea what language its coded in.

Comment: are you grabbing the string directly following `<a href="` every time and using it to replace `<a href=".../a>`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. We're here to help you with *specific* problems you run into *while trying to solve it on your own*. I suggest you start reading up a bit on regex, and solve it yourself. If, after trying yourself, you still can't get it to work - come back here and post what you've tried. We'll be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: I understand that Joseph, and if you look at all my previous questions you will see that they are all usually well researched and do exactly what you describe. As i said im a complete novice to regex, therefore i have no idea about how much work is involved in creating a regex like this. If what i am asking is outside the boundaries of reason then i apologize.

Comment: If you just want to parse URLs, see Gruber's regex. http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls.

Comment: @ScottStevens Did you get what you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a Rubyist, so my example is going to be in Ruby. I'd recommend using two regexes, just to keep things straight:

```
url_reg = /<a href="(.*?)"/   # Matches first string within <a href=""> tag
tag_reg = /(<a href=.*?a>)/   # Matches entire <a href>...</a> tag
```

You'll want to pull the URL with the first regex out and store it temporarily, then replace the entire contents of the tag (matched with the tag_reg) with the stored URL.

You might be able to combine it, but it doesn't seem like a good idea. You're fundamentally altering (by deleting) the original tag, and replacing it with something inside itself. Less chance of things going wrong if you separate those two steps as much as possible.

**Example in Ruby**

```
def replace_tag(input)
  url_reg = /<a href="(.*?)"/    # Match URLS within an <a href> tag
  tag_reg = /(<a href=.*?a>)/     # Match an entire <a href></a> tag

  while (input =~ tag_reg) # While the input has matching <a href> tags
    url = input.scan(url_reg).flatten[0]  # Retrieve the first URL match
    input = input.sub(tag_reg, url)       # Replace first tag contents with URL
  end

  return input
end

File.open("test.html", "r") do |html_input|       # Open original HTML file
  File.open("output.html", "w") do |html_output|  # Open an output file
    while line = html_input.gets                  # Read each line
      output = replace_tag(line)                  # Perform necessary substitutions
      html_output.puts(output)                    # Write output lines to file
    end
  end
end
```

Even if you don't use Ruby, I hope the example makes sense. I tested this on your given input file, and it produces the expected output.

Comment: Your regex may match `<a href="http://google.com">First</a><a href="http://bing.com">Second</a>` as one regex, removing both and leaving only `http://google.com`.

Comment: @HansZ It does not. You can test it yourself if you like. You'll note the `.*?a>` in the tag regex, which should tell it to stop looking when it hits the first `a>`. This is why the replacement needs to be run in a loop, for each match. It can't all be done in one go if there are multiple matching tags.

Comment: While this particular regex doesn't in ruby, in other, less strict greedy/not greedy regex languages, this will not hold always. Sorry for ambiguous comment, I was commenting on the regex itself, not your particular implementation.

Comment: @HansZ Alright, I'll give you that. Unfortunately he didn't tell us what language he's planning on using...

Answer (score 2):

ScottStevens, it is well known that trying to parse html with regex is difficult, in fact, there is quite a [verbose post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) on this issue. However, if those are the only two formats the `<a>` ever takes, here is the approach to the problem:

Your first clue on how to approach this problem is that both tags start with `<a href="`, and you want to take that out, and for that, a simple remove on `'<a href="'` will do, no regex required.

Your next clue is that sometimes, your end tag sometimes has `">...</a>` and sometimes has `" rel=...</a>` (what goes between rel= and  doesn't matter from a regex point of view). Now notice that `" rel="...</a>` contains within it somewhere a `">...</a>`. This means you can remove `" rel="...</a>` in two steps, remove `" rel="...` up to the `">`, and then remove `">...</a>`. Additionally, to make sure you remove between only one tag of `<a...>...</a>`, add the additional constraint that in the `...` of `">...</a>`, there cannot be any `<a`.

That and a [regex cheat sheet](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) can help you get started.

---

That said, you should really use an html parser. [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Comment: While I agree that parsing HTML as a whole is a problem well outside the scope of regular expressions, if all he needs it replacement for a single tag, understanding its construction, it's perfectly doable.

Comment: @KChaloux It's often easier and more widely applicable to use an html parser to build a document, then to access its children accordingly, than to try to write perfect regex for your html tags, however limited the scope is. In one case, you're working with trees. The other case you're working with letter combinations.